# File was replaced during merge

Tags: git

look at this sequence:

First, i am cloning an empty repository:

```
      git clone http://mygitlabserver/myuser/project1.git
      cd project1
```

Then i create a main.c file with this content:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        return 0;
}
```

I add and commit this very first version of my program:

```
git add main.c 
git commit -m "first version"
```

Then, i create a branch and i switch to this branch:

```
git branch branch1
git checkout branch1
```

In this branch, i made a change to main.c file:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        return 1;
}
```

As you can see, this is a very basic change (0 to 1).

I add and commit this change on branch1:

```
git add main.c 
git commit -m "version with return 1"
```

Now, i want to merge branch1 to master branch. Here is what i type:

```
git checkout master
git merge branch1
```

I have no warning about conflict and this is what i do not understand.
Here is content of main.c file now in master branch:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    return 1;
}
```

So my main.c file was replaced by the one in branch1. Sometimes, i see my main.c file with something like this:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
==============================
        return 0;
==============================
        return 1;
==============================
    }
```

But this was not the case in my example. My question is... Why?

Thanks

Comment: This is expected behaviour. Try to think about git in terms of commits not lists of changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no conflict. Both branches have same history with last commit "first version" and this commit is the last one on `main` branch, which makes the merging trivial. Merging `branch1` to `master` applies commit "version with return 1" the same way you have applied it when you created it on `branch1`.

If you have created for e.g. a commit "version with return 2" on `main` branch (which obviously changes `return 0` to `return 2`), then histories would have diverged AND differences would apply to the same part of file. This would result in conflict.